# heroku postgress images not displaying ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, erb, materialize, heroku-postgres

#### The Problem

Having trouble with displaying users uploaded photo from heroku postgress in a materialize slider. It only displays once a user uploads a new picture. Anything previously uploaded (while deployed on heroku) doesn't display. I also get a **Failed to load resource 404 in the browser console** on the page that is supposed to display the image slider.

#### Attempted solutions

I've tried running the terminal command 'heroku run rails assets:precompile' which still does not work. My local version works fine with no problems. I'm not sure if this is a Materialize looking in the

#### Here's the [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZAUP.png)

[image]

#### Here's the [erd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJaI0.png)

[image]

Comment: Where are you uploading the photo and are you using some gem like carrierwave? I am not familiar with materialize. You post.photo is a string, does it include different fields or it just the url of the picture? Do you have this problem with the development version of the website? If yes, this could be connected with the asset pipeline and would be easy finding out. You just inspect your image and check the `src` tag. If they are not `http://yourdomain.com/assets/yourimage.jpb`, then that could be the problem. Also where are the images saved when  you work in development?In your public/assets?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is read-only system so you can't upload images to heroku.

You have to upload images to Amazone S3 or cloudinary servers using carrierwave gem.

Answer (score 0):

Running `heroku run rails assets:precompile` will have no effect. Whenever you invoke `heroku run` command, a new one-off dyno is created, the command is executed and then dyno is killed. Those changes will not be reflected on your actual web server. And btw it should be `rake assets:precompile`.

Second thing, `assets:precompile` works for application static assets like javascripts, stylesheets and images that are part of your web design. You don't use it for user-uploaded images.

I think your problem is that you just upload user photo somewhere inside your app directory. Maybe in `public` or so like it was mentioned in the comment. This won't work on Heroku, because you don't have persistent storage. Any changes on disk will be gone after next deploy or restart. What you need to do is to store uploaded files somewhere else, ie. Amazon S3. If you are using some gem for uploading (carrierwave or paperclip), it should pretty easy to setup.

Comment: Awesome, I will give this a shot. Navigating Heroku can be somewhat daunting, thanks for the feedback!